# Solidity throws UnhandledRejections detected after migration is finished

Tags: migration, solidity, nft

I have an error after solidity migration.

The code is based on the youtube video(part 1 and part 2).

"I BUILT AN NFT GAME IN 12 HOURS (Part 1) - Building the Ethereum Smart Contract.mp4"

The original codes throws error before the 2_token_migration.js is finished.

So, I changed the Token.sol as following.

```
const Token = artifacts.require("Token");
module.exports = async function (deployer) {
  await deployer.deploy(Token, "NFT Game", "NFTG");
  Token.deployed().then(async function (tokenInstance) {
    tokenInstance.mint(100, 200, 100000);
    let pet = await tokenInstance.getTokenDetails(0);
    console.log('pet: ', pet);
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log('caught', error.message);
  });
};
```

It runs successful, but throws a new exception "UnhandledRejections detected".

```
UnhandledRejections detected
Promise {
  <rejected> Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
      at D:\Study\nft\test-3\migrations\2_token_migration.js:16:19
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5) {
    data: {
      '0xb03a68fed3e50abda1702ad0d871d7eee6876ce0d9261d3b230079b9c46ebc20': [Object],
      stack: 'RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert\n' +
        '    at Function.RuntimeError.fromResults (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\lib\\utils\\runtimeerror.js:94:13)\n' +
        '    at BlockchainDouble.processBlock (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.5.4.0_x64__5dg5pnz03psnj\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\lib\\blockchain_double.js:627:24)\n' +
        '    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)\n' +
        '    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)',
      name: 'RuntimeError'
    },
```

Can anyone fix this error?

Comment: The error is most likely originated in the `Token` contract `constructor`. Please edit your question and paste the contract code as well (the current code is the JS migration script) ... Also, from the error stack it seems like you're using Ganache emulator. Can you confirm that? Or are you deploying the token to a different network (such as Ropsten testnet)?

Comment: Hi, Mr. Petr.
I reposted my question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70150211/solidity-throws-unhandledrejections-detected-after-migration-is-finished2 including Token source code. Please resolve my issues.